Strong Law of Large Numbers for martingale difference sequence
Could anyone provide a reference for the following theorem?
Theorem. Suppose that $\{X_k\}$ is a martingale difference sequence, that is to say $\mathbb{E}(|X_k|) < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_k \mathrel{|} X_1, ..., X_{k-1}) = 0$ for each $k \ge 1$. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(X_k^2)/k^2 < \infty$, then $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k \to 0$ almost surely.
N.B.

Instead of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(X_k^2)/k^2 < \infty$, the following stronger assumption is sufficient for my application: $\sup_{k\ge 1}\|X_k\|_\infty < \infty$.

This theorem can be found (with proofs) at, e.g.,
Law of Large Numbers for Martingales
but no reference is given. I would like to apply this theorem in a paper (without repeating its proof) and hence a reference is needed.

The following post
Law of Large Numbers for Martingale Difference Sequences (in probability)
suggests Chow 1971, which establishes the convergence under the (weaker) assumption that $\{X_k\}$ is uniformly integrable. This is nice. However, a reference presenting the above-mentioned theorem would be better.



Can you clarify the notation for your stronger assumption? E.g. if $X_k$ are i.i.d. standard normal then the sum of $\mathbb E[|X_k|^2]/k^2$ is finite but $\sup_{k\ge 0}|X_k|$ is infinite almost surely. I'm not sure what $|X_k|\infty$ is intended to mean in this case. Is it  $\sup{\omega\in\Omega}|X_k(\omega)|$?

Hi @Wei, thanks for your comment. You are right. The infinity norm is as you defined. Your example shows that the norm assumption is strictly stronger. Thank you.

Then the $X_k$ are uniformly integrable and you can use the Chow 1971 result. Or are you looking for more than that?

Yes. This is nice. However, a reference presenting the above-mentioned theorem would be better.

You can directly apply the theorem in Chow 1967, which states the following.
Let $Y_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ be a martingale such that there exists $\alpha \ge 1$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(|X_k|^{2\alpha}) / k^{1+\alpha} \;<\; \infty,
$$
then we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n / n = 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Greet. This is what I need. Thank you.

For those who are interested, Chow's theorem is a consequence of Theorem 2, Chow 1960 and Theorem 9, Burkholder 1966. Chow 1967 mentions these references but does not specify the theorems.

This is an application of Theorem 2.18 page 35 in
Martingale Limit Theory and Its Application
Hall, P.; Heyde, C. C..
Indeed, this result says that if $(X_i)$ is a martingale difference sequence and $(U_n)$ a nondecreasing sequence of positive random variables such that $U_n$ is $\mathcal F_{n-1}$-measurable, then $U_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges almost surely to $0$ on the set $\{U_n\to\infty\}\cap \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty U_i^{-p}\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_i \rvert^p\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]<\infty\right\}$.
Apply this with $p=2$ and $U_n=n$. Note that the non-negative random variable $\sum_{i=1}^\infty U_i^{-p}\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_i \rvert^p\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]=
\sum_{i=1}^\infty  i^{-2}\mathbb E\left[  X_i  ^2\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]$
is almost surely finite, since by assumption and the monotone convergence theorem, its expectation is finite.

Define $T_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n {X_k\over k}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$. This is a martingale, and
$$
\Bbb E[T_n^2]=\sum_{k=1}^n{\Bbb E[X_k^2]\over k^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\Bbb E[X_k^2]\over k^2}<\infty.
$$
That is, $(T_n)$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale, hence a.s. convergent. Now apply Kronecker's lemma to conclude that $\lim_n{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k=0$ a.s.
